# open file manager using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, parse-platform

I want to be able to open file manager and pick lets say a song or image. And then save then save to Parse server. I think because I'm using a fragment the intent needs to be called from a different method. But the app crashes, any help would much appreciated.

```
public class UploadFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)       { 

    View rootView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.upload_fragment, container, false);


     Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById (R.id.uploadBtn);

      // Capture button clicks

      button.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener () {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String path="File Path";
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setData(Uri.parse (String.valueOf (path)));

            startActivity(intent);

            byte [] data = "".getBytes ();

            // Create the ParseFile
            ParseFile file  = new ParseFile ("ad.png", data);
            // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
            file.saveInBackground ();

            // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
            ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject ("Ads");

            // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
            imgupload.put ("Ads", "AndroidBegin Logo");

            // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
            imgupload.put ("ImageFile", file);

            // Create the class and the columns
            imgupload.saveInBackground ();

            // Show a simple toast message
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
        });
       return  rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think every phone has file manager like my Xperia Z. I was developing a app using file manager but it caused problems on a lot of devices. A good way is to create your own file manager...

Comment: I don't know how to do that but I had a feeling I was.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a file manager class.